# PostgreSQL - batch + script + variable

Tags: postgresql, variables, batch-file

I am not a programmer, I am struggling a bit with this.

I have a batch file connecting to my PostgreSQL server, and then open a sql script. Everything works as expected. My question is how to pass a variable (if possible) from one to the other.

Here is my batch file:

```
set PGPASSWORD=xxxx
cls
@echo off
C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\8.3\bin\psql -d Total -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -f C:\TotalProteinImport.sql
```

And here's the script:

```
copy totalprotein from 'c:/TP.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER;

update anagrafica
set pt=(select totalprotein.resultvalue from totalprotein where totalprotein.accessionnbr=anagrafica.id)
where data_analisi = '12/23/2011';

delete from totalprotein;
```

This is working great, now the question is how could I pass a variable that would carry the date for `data_analisi`?
Like in the batch file, "Please enter date", and then the value is passed to the sql script.

Comment: Sign is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [create a function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) out of your your SQL script like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_myfunc(date)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

CREATE TEMP TABLE t_tmp ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT * FROM totalprotein LIMIT 0; -- copy table-structure from table

COPY t_tmp FROM 'c:/TP.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER;

UPDATE anagrafica a
SET    pt = t.resultvalue
FROM   t_tmp t
WHERE  a.data_analisi = $1
AND    t.accessionnbr = a.id;

-- Temp table is dropped automatically at end of session
-- In this case (ON COMMIT DROP) after the transaction

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

You can use [language SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html) for this kind of simple SQL batch.

As you can see I have made a couple of modifications to your script that should make it faster, cleaner and safer.

#### Major points

- For reading data into an empty table temporarily, use a [temporary table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html). Saves a lot of disc writes and is much faster.
- To simplify the process I use your existing table `totalprotein` as template for the creation of the (empty) temp table.
- If you want to delete all rows of a table use TRUNCATE instead of DELETE FROM. Much faster. In this particular case, you need neither. The temporary table is dropped automatically. See comments in function.
- The way you updated `anagrafica.pt` you would set the column to `NULL`, if **anything** goes wrong in the process (`date` not found, wrong `date`, `id` not found ...). The way I rewrote the UPDATE, it only happens if matching data are found. I assume that is what you actually want.

Then ask for user input in your shell script and call the function with the date as parameter. That's how it could work in a Linux shell (as user postgres, with password-less access (using `IDENT` method in [`pg_haba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)):

```sh
#! /bin/sh

# Ask for date. 'YYYY-MM-DD' = ISO date-format, valid with any postgres locale.
echo -n "Enter date in the form YYYY-MM-DD and press [ENTER]: "
read date

# check validity of $date ...
psql db -p5432 -c "SELECT f_myfunc('$date')"
```

`-c` makes psql execute a singe SQL command and then exits. I wrote a lot more on [psql and its command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8595568/939860) yesterday in a somewhat related answer.

The creation of the according *Windows batch file* remains as exercise for you.

---

#### Call under Windows

The error message tells you:

> Function tpimport(unknown) does not exist

Note the lower case letters: `tpimport`. I suspect you used mixe case letters to create the function. So now you have to enclose the function name in double quotes every time you use it.

Try this one (edited quotes!):

```
C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\8.3\bin\psql -d Total -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
                                    -c "SELECT ""TPImport""('%dateimport%')"
```

Note how I use **singe and double quotes** here. I *guess* this could work under windows. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script).

You made it hard for yourself when you chose to use **mixed case identifiers** in PostgreSQL - a folly which I never tire of warning against. Now you have to double quote the function name `"TPImport"` every time you use it. While perfectly legit, I would *never* do that. I use lower case letters for identifiers. Always. This way I never mix up lower / upper case and I never have to use double quotes.

The **ultimate fix** would be to recreate the function with a lower case name (just leave away the double quotes and it will be folded to lower case automatically). Then the function name will just work without any quoting.

Read the [basics about identifiers here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).
Also, consider upgrading to a more recent version of PostgreSQL 8.3 is a bit rusty by now.

Comment: Thanks Erwin for all the information! Now...It looks like when I call the function from PGAdmin, it runs properly. If I try to run it from my batch file, it says the function does not exist. Where does the function need to be written? Right now I have it under my database, "Schema", "Public", "Functions". But it looks like this is unavailable from psql -c "SELECT "myfunction"('%dateimport%')". That same command works just fine in pgadmin (typing a specific date).

Comment: @damien: You need to provide the name of your database like I did in my code example: `psql` **db** `-c "SELECT myfunction('%dateimport%')"`. If you don't, you will connect to the default maintenance database of the name `postgres`, and the function will not be found there. Also, don't include the pair of double quotes around the function name. It breaks the quoting.

Comment: Erwin, sorry I didn't write the full detail... the whole command line is: C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\8.3\bin\psql -d Total -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -c "SELECT "TPImport"('%dateimport%')". I remove the quotes but the same problem occurs, "Function tpimport(unknown) does not exist", then "LINE1: SELECT TPImport('12/27/2011')". "HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts." That same line from PGAdmin with the quotes SELECT "TPImport"('12/27/2011') works fine...

Comment: I fixed it! Thanks Erwin for your help! The problem was that by creating the function through pgadmin's "New Function", it would create it as : CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "tpimport"(dateimport timestamp without time zone)
  RETURNS void AS etc....   I deleted the function, and created it again through SQL statement "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tpimport(dateimport timestamp without time zone)
  RETURNS void AS etc...". Removing the quotes around tpimport worked. I actually had the same issues with creating table before...through pgadmin it uses quotes around the table names, which makes them

Comment: @damien: my advise is to *never* use double quotes around identifiers and always use lower case. Makes your life easier. :) However, in this case .. "tpimport" .. all lower case .. double quotes without effect .. no problem to begin with. Never mind, it works.

Answer (score 2):

`psql` supports textual replacement variables. Within `psql` they can be set using `\set` and used using `:varname`.

```
\set xyz 'abcdef'
select :'xyz';
 ?column? 
----------
abcdef
```

These variables can be set using command line arguments also:

```
psql -v xyz=value
```

The only problem is that these textual replacements always need some fiddling with quoting as shown by the first `\set` and `select`.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the function in Postgres, you must create a .bat file in the bin directory of your Postgres version, for example `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin`. Here you write:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin
psql -p 5432 -h localhost -d myDataBase -U postgres -c "select * from myFunction()"
```