# How do I use SQL commands inside SH script

Tags: database, postgresql, sh

My current script looks something like this:

```
!/bin/sh 
sudo -u postgres createdb mydb
sudo -u postgres psql mydb
CREATE TABLE person (first VARCHAR(32), last VARCHAR(32));
CREATE TABLE thing (size VARCHAR(32), price VARCHAR(32));
exit 0;
```

As of right now, when I execute the script it creates the database and logs me into it.  However, after it logs me into mydb the script does not continue to do the `CREATE TABLE` commands.

I'm new when it comes to this stuff so I have no idea if I'm going about this the right way.  Basically I just want a script that creates a database and then a few tables inside it (using PostgreSQL).

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942632/how-to-extrace-pg-backend-pid-from-postgresql-in-shell-script-and-pass-it-to-ano/8305578#8305578

Comment: Once you log into postgres your script waits because you're in another application.  Take a look at the question and answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594717/bash-shell-script-to-execute-pgsql-commands-in-files it is related to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

psql -d mydb -U postgres -c "CREATE TABLE person (first VARCHAR(32), last VARCHAR(32));"
psql -d mydb -U postgres -c "CREATE TABLE thing (size VARCHAR(32), price VARCHAR(32));"
```

You can run all queries with -c option.

Comment: Hey thank you so much man this is the method that I ended up using.

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use a `here-doc` (this is a shell feature and depends on what shell you're running):

```
psql mydb <<EOF
    CREATE TABLE person (first VARCHAR(32), last VARCHAR(32));
    CREATE TABLE thing (size VARCHAR(32), price VARCHAR(32));
EOF
```

Another would be to write the commands to a sufficiently protected (with permissions) temporary file and then pass that as a script to `postgres` with the `-f FILENAME` option.

Comment: Note that you can use `$variable` substitutions in your here document, substituting shell variables into the SQL. If you don't want to do that you should usually quote the here-document to prevent substitution, eg `<<'__EOF__'` instead of `<<__EOF__`. Unexpected and exciting results arise when you use things like `$1` or dollar-quoting in SQL without quoting your here-documents.

Answer (score 1):

After editing the hba_conf file to "local all postgres trust" (I used trust so I wouldn't have to supply a password for my scripts), I used TraviJuu's suggestion and it now my script works flawlessly.  Here is what the end result looks like.

!/bin/sh

sudo -u postgres createdb mydb

psql -w -d mydb -U postgres -c "CREATE TABLE person (first VARCHAR(32), last VARCHAR(32));"

psql -w -d mydb -U postgres -c "CREATE TABLE thing (size VARCHAR(32), price VARCHAR(32));"

exit 0;