# How to execute "DROP OWNED BY" only if the user exists?

Tags: postgresql, psql, roles, ddl, privileges

I'm trying to write a bash script that will create a Postgres database, as well as the user and the user privileges to access that database. I'm using Postgres 9.6. I have the below ...

```sh
create_db_command="SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = '$DB_NAME')\gexec"
drop_owned_by_command="DROP OWNED BY $DB_USER;"
drop_role_command="DROP ROLE IF EXISTS $DB_USER;"
create_user_command="create user $DB_USER with encrypted password '$DB_PASS';"
grant_privs_command="grant all privileges on database $DB_NAME to $DB_USER;"

PGPASSWORD=$ROOT_PASSWORD
# This command creates the db if it doesn't already exist
echo "SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = '$DB_NAME')\gexec" | psql -U$PG_USER
psql -U$PG_USER $DB_NAME -c "$drop_owned_by_command"
psql -U$PG_USER -c "$drop_role_command"
psql -U$PG_USER -c "$create_user_command"
psql -U$PG_USER -c "$grant_privs_command"
```

The problem is when the script is run the very first time, the command

```
DROP OWNED BY $DB_USER;
```

fails because the user does not yet exist. Is there a way to write the above command so that it will only run if the user exists? Similar to `DROP USER IF EXISTS ...`, but `DROP OWNED` has no `IF EXISTS` clause.

Comment: Two major directions you could come at this from: One is trying to detect and handle the case inside your psql code, the other is trying to detect and handle it from bash. Personally, I'd suggest the former.

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING as a place to start

Comment: Why not use the same pattern as you use for `CREATE DATABASE`, except `WHERE EXISTS`.

Comment: I'd be open to that, but I'm not clear what the WHERE clause would look like.

Comment: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = $DB_USER`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a similar technique like you already have for `CREATE DATABASE`.
In the shell:

```sh
drop_owned_by_command="SELECT 'DROP OWNED BY $DB_USER' FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = '$DB_USER'\gexec"

echo $drop_owned_by_command | psql -U$PG_USER $DB_NAME
```

The `SELECT` only returns a row (containing the DDL command) if the role a actually exists. This is in turn executed by the psql command `\gexec`.

So we have a combination of SQL and psql commands and cannot use `psql -c` since, [quoting the manual on `--command`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

> ***`command`*** must be either a command string that is completely parsable by the server (i.e., it contains no psql-specific features),
> or a single backslash command. Thus you cannot mix SQL and psql
> meta-commands within a `-c` option.

Instead, pipe the echo to psql like demonstrated - and like suggested in the manual and in my related answer below and like you already do for `CREATE DATABASE`.

Related:

- [Simulate CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS for PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389124/simulate-create-database-if-not-exists-for-postgresql/18389184#18389184)
- [Shell script to execute pgsql commands in files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594717/shell-script-to-execute-pgsql-commands-in-files/8595568#8595568)